# What is cyberstalking?

Tags: united-kingdom, internet, harassment

What constitutes cyberstalking? If I contacted a person online 4 times is that cyberstalking? (3 times were over email apologising for accidentally nearly logging onto their account and the 4th time I replied to a question, using a different account, that they posted on a forum which was about trying to identify who has been sending them emails. That question was asked weeks ago and days before I made the mistake of accidentally nearly logging on. I’ve subsequently deleted my reply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no legal definition of cyberstalking- it is simply an extension of regular stalking and harrassment.

Suffice to say, there is no hard limit on how many times you can talk to the same person. I'm not sure why you thought there would be.

Besides attempting to log into their account (and even that isn't a crime if it was accidental and unsuccessful), nothing you have done has broken the law.